# How to use Android R.java in other applications (web, for example)?

Tags: java, android, mobile, web

The Android Resource Management is very interesting to me. And I'm asking my self if there's a way to use it in other applications, like web, for example.

I want to do this because I find it very easy to manage and to use.

Is there a way to do that? To use an `R.java` Resources Management in other applications, not only in android?

Comment: It's only a key-value pair list. Like the SharedPreferences. **ANY** configuration file will do. What **R.java** does is to add an integer id to a textual name. Well, to any resource files and constants and to any View.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible for programmers to write a code generator that generates a Java class named `R.java`? Or are you asking if an Android project and processed with Android development tools can generate non-Android output?

Comment: @CommonsWare Your first question. In Android applications there's the XML files to add de values. And the R.java is compiled based on that XML. My goal is to have something like that in a web application, for example.

Comment: Then I guess that I do not understand your question. Clearly, it is possible for programmers to write code that will code-generate an `R.java` class. Not only do the Android tools do it (and programmers wrote those tools), but `R.java` is just a text file, and programmers have been creating text files for decades. Code generation itself has been around for a couple of decades, at least.

Comment: @CommonsWare Indeed. But there's some API Android use to do that? Of course I can implement that, but better if there's an API I could use.

Comment: "But there's some API Android use to do that?" -- whether they are using some code-generation library to assist, I can't say, as I haven't gone looking for it. Since this code generation is performed by **`aapt`** (AFAIK), that code generation probably would be done in C/C++, as **`aapt`** is a platform-native binary. You might poke around [the **`aapt`** source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/tools/aapt/) and see what you find.

Comment: Right. I'll do that. Can you answer the question just to finish this discussion?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is unanswered for too long, I'll compile the comments from @CommonsWare and @Rotwang.

My question is not very clear. Of course it's possible to use something close to Android Resource Management in other applications. But the concept is based in the language limitations too. For example, React and React native have a completely different way to manage resources because the language has its specific behavior.

Quoting @CommonsWare

> Whether they are using some code-generation library to assist, I can't say, as I haven't gone looking for it. Since this code generation is performed by aapt (AFAIK), that code generation probably would be done in C/C++, as aapt is a platform-native binary. You might poke around the aapt source and see what you find.